# Why do I need to pass strings by reference to my swap function?

Tags: c#, .net, string, value-type, reference-type

In C#, string is a reference type. Then,

Why do I need to have my swap function to have ref parameters?

```
swap(ref string first, ref string second) //swap(string first, string second) doesn't work
{
     temp = first;
     first = second
     second = temp;
}
```

Comment: Might be worth reading this article: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Your confusion stems from a misunderstanding of what the `ref` keyword does. Have a read of the article.

Comment: By default, everything is pass-by-value in C#. References are passed by value so normal method calls pass a *copy* of the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `string` is a reference type and this

```
void swap(string first, string second)
```

passes references to the `string` objects to the function.
But `string` is immutable so it is not possible for the swap function to change the objects through these references. For strings, the only way to implement a swap function is to use the ref keyword to pass the references by reference so the references can be swapped.

OTOH, if you have a mutable class, you can write a swap function without using the ref keyword:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

static void Swap(Foo first, Foo second)
{
    var temp = first.Bar;
    first.Bar = second.Bar;
    second.Bar = temp;
}

Foo foo1 = new Foo { Bar = 1 };
Foo foo1Copy = foo1;
Foo foo2 = new Foo { Bar = 2 };
Swap(foo1, foo2);
```

But note, that after the swap, foo1Copy.Bar == 2, since the object referenced by foo1 and foo1Copy was modified.

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing two different kinds of references. Strings are references to *instances*. Your swap function takes references to *variables*.

Think about it this way. You have two books, "A Christmas Carol" and "Pickwick Papers". They're books; they've got pages and text and whatnot.

You have ten pieces of paper. Five says "A Christmas Carol". Five says "Pickwick Papers". The papers are *references* to the books. They're not the books.

You have ten drawers labelled A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J. You put the papers that says "A Christmas Carol" into drawer A through E, and the papers that says "Pickwick Papers" into drawers F through J.

Now you want to swap the contents of drawers E and I. **What information do you have to give to the swapper?** You can't tell the swapper "Swap references to Christmas Carol for Pickwick Papers", because that would change all ten drawers, not just E and I. The information you have to give to the swapper is "E" and "I". You have to pass reference to two *variables*; the fact that the variables themselves contain a reference to a book is irrelevant.

Your swapper has three drawers of its own, labelled first, second and temp. It takes two piece of paper. One says "E", and that goes in the drawer labelled "first". One says "I" and that goes in the drawer labelled "second".

The swapper looks in "first" and finds a paper that says "E". It looks in "E" and finds a paper that says "Christmas Carol". It makes a photocopy of that paper and puts the copy in "temp"... and you see how this goes from here I hope.

Answer (score 3):

Because parameters in C# by default are passed by value, not reference. Adding `ref` gives you pass-by-reference behavior.

Comment: But, If I create an object of a custom class and pass it as a parameter, I don't use ref. Aren't string and custom class object same? Thanks.

Comment: @Raja Nakka: Try to pass the object without ref, assign it to null inside the method and check the value when the method returns. You will see that any assignments without ref will not be visible.

Comment: @Raja: If you create an object of a custom class and pass it as a parameter to a swap function, you *would* use ref if you were trying to swap the references themselves.  But usually you would end up swapping the contents via a member, like in [Hennik's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8604821).

Answer (score 3):

The reference to the string is passed by value. There's a big difference between passing a reference by value and passing an object by reference. It's unfortunate that the word "reference" is used in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an object into a method, you are passing the actual object and not the address in memory of the object. You could not then assign a new value to it as you would be changing what object is stored in a memory address elsewhere, not the original.

By adding the `ref` keyword, you pass the objects by reference. This means you essentially give the method access to the address where the objects are stored, so when you swap the objects, the original memory addresses will then refer to the swapped object.

Comment: It's also not copied when it's passed in.

Answer (score 0):

String is a reference type. It is passed by value to the method by default. If you actually want to change the value of the string, you need to pass it by reference. The below msdn article explains it in detail.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28(v=vs.80).aspx